# Cannot see Tenant Setting when already a Power BI Administrator

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I need to enable Service principal API access.

I am already a Power BI Administrator and also a Global Administrator (as shown below)
[image]

I still cannot seet Tenant Settings on Power BI Admin Portal
[image]

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to find Tenant Setting in my environment by assigning the roles and got the same result as below:***

[image]

**To resolve the error, make sure to create an Administrative unit and add the user like below:**

[image]

**Assign the Power BI Administrator/Global Administrator to the user like below:**

*Click on the user -> Assigned roles -> Add Assignments*

[image]

Make sure to login to the `PowerBI Admin Portal` with the same user account and the **Tenant Setting** will be visible like below:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rukmini. I already added Global administrator and Power BI administrator on my user as seen above screenshots. But still I cannot access Tenant Settings.

Comment: Please try assigning the roles as mentioned above and try to check.